# How to configure both apache and tomcat on same url?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy, url

Say I have a registered URL `mywebsite.com` pointing to my server with a public IP address.

I want to run both tomcat and apache to serve pages (i.e., some static pages on apache and some dynamic pages on tomcat, like jsp etc...).

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that apache is listening on 80 and tomcat on 8080.

I heard about `mod_proxy`. Is it possible to have requests to `mywebsite.com` go to apache and `mywebsite/loggedin` go to tomcat? If yes, how should this be configured and where? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `mod_jk`--it tends to be more specific than `mod_proxy`, and easier to debug.  You can forward contexts.  I.e., if I have `webapp1` and `webapp2` running on Tomcat, and I have an `images` directory on Apache, this would work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    JKMount /webapp1/* ajp13
    JKMount /webapp2/* ajp13
    Alias /images "/some/local/dir"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is also much easier to configure, and most distributions already have packages in their native package managers.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

mod_proxy works well with tomcat. There are 2 ways to proxy to tomcat via mod_proxy.

1. http - So tomcat runs as an http server to and apache talks to tomcat via HTTP
2. mod_proxy_ajp - This uses the ajp protocol (also used by mod_jk). In this case apache talks to tomcat via a binary protocol which has some better performance.

mod_proxy_ajp is a package which comes with apache as compared to mod_jk which needs to be downloaded and compiled. But mod_jk usually gets new features first and has more options. If your setup is NOT complex ... mod_proxy_ajp is the way to go. In which case in Tomcat, you need to configure tomcat to have a AJP connector. And you will not need an http connector in server.xml. For apache the directive may be as easy as this:

```
  ProxyPass /loggedin  ajp://127.0.0.2:8009/loggedin
```

Proxy docs with ajp examples are here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks, I am currently doing a lot of reading following the answers so far. I surely need a simple solution right now, but I know I'll need something more sophisticated in the future. Climbing the learning curve.